# Develop Chrome Mobile content capture extension

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have a website written in WebJS and it doesn't display well on webview. I want to develop a Chrome extension to capture all website content. Any idea to do that?

P/s: Because of web technique, I can't use webview to capture!

Comment: Chrome for android does not support extensions/plugins.

Comment: @leppie: Have any solution to capture full web browser in android? Dont user webview in native app, just process in browser.

Comment: You could use the embedded webview maybe?

Comment: The website created base on WebJS, so webview couldn't display all components.